# PIC 18F micro stops receiving over UART after several hours of working fine

Tags: pic, uart

I'm working on a project using a PIC 18F25K80 to talk to an nRF24L01 radio. To help debug and control the program, I included code to communicate over the serial port with my PC. The program transmits a timestamp to the PC every second so I know its functioning. I can also send commands to the micro from the PC to perform certain functions such as reply with the code version. I have three of these boards and a program I use to talk to all three at once from my PC.

This all works well for several hours but after being on for ~4 hours, one of the boards (eventually all three) stops recognizing my serial commands. They all continue transmitting the timestamp but won't respond to any commands. I am communicating through a virtual serial port using a USB-Serial adapter so I suspected a problem there. So I swapped two of the adapters and the problem remained with the board. I scoped the serial receive pin right at the micro while sending a command and the data does make it to the micro.

The real dilemma is this; cycling power to the micro does not fix the problem. Shutting down the PC and re-powering does not fix the problem. But, if I power off everything and leave it off for 12-24 ours before re-powering, everything works normally. A friend suggested there might be a buffer that gets overrun after a period of time that needs to be re-initialed. But wouldn't powering it off/on even for a few minutes reset all registers/buffers? Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

I have discovered why this problem cannot be cleared with a simple power cycle to the micro. The USB-Serial dongle, if left connected, maintains some logic voltage at the serial port of the micro. This voltage finds its way through the micro logic and appears as 1V on the 3.3V bus to the micro. If I remove power from the micro and disconnect the dongle, this voltage goes to zero and seems to clear the micro properly. The problem with serial communication is reset and the micro, when re-powered, works normally, at least for a while. The original problem remains, however, where the micro eventually stops acknowledging serial data received. I checked the grounds from the USB-serial adapter and it is there and secure. I scoped the serial data at the receive pin of the micro before failure and during failure and it is always there. I am in the process of trying to pin down how long it takes for the problem to present itself after powering up. Normally, I am sending commands over serial randomly while debugging, so it is hard to say how many messages the micro receives before failing. So, I modified my serial prog on the PC to send messages automatically at 6S intervals and log all serial data sent back from the micro to a file. Each message sent elicits a response from the micro so it is easy to see when the failure occurs. I ran this test for over 12 hours but never could reproduce the failure. It only seems to fail when I manually send messages. I continue to look for the distinction between these two scenarios.

Comment: pfff, long story, can you pinpoint to a specific question? Note that there are buttons to up or downvote your question. If you hover you will see 'does the Q show research effort, is it useful and clear', where useful is meant in the sense that also others with a similar problem may benefit.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to be specific. The question is why does the Micro stop receiving serial messages after working fine for several hours?

Comment: I am afraid that nobody really cares about that problem, unless there is something generic about it. Most people who often find answers to their (generic) problems here, occasionally try to answer (generic) questions in return. So try to frame your question a bit generic. Also, don't make it too hard to understand your problem. Sometimes, a picture says more than a thousand words. Make your problem a bit more interesting to others. Most of us do not get paid to answer questions.

Comment: There are too many places that the issue can be at. For starters you could at least isolate whether it is on the sending side or receiving side by probing the signals with scope *after* the failure, or by replacing either the sender or the receiver with something else.

Comment: Increase the timestamp rate (0.5s) and double the command rate - see if operating time halves - sounds like the receive buffer fills up, then can't receive any more.  Put a breakpoint on the buffer pointer and spam commands to see what the pointer does.

Comment: Have you connected the GND wire between your USB-Serial adapter and your PIC, or only the TX & RX wires?

Comment: could be a power supply issue, or an overheating issue ... a reset should clear a problem immediately

Comment: Check the accuracy of the baudrate of the software serial. Reduce the baudrate. Maybe the soft-serial has some bug somewhere. Try to regularly close/reopen the soft serial device (once an hour or so). First I thought of something triggered by temperature... but maybe thaths not the case after your last comments. No chance to switch to a hardware serial?

Comment: The usual reason is receive errors not being handled correctly. Show us your code.